# React Navigation RedirectUrl implementation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using React Navigation in a React Native app. I manage the login step with the auth flow they say. This is, if I have a token stored then user is logged in, otherwise it is not.

I provide several Universal links to my app and some of them needs the user to be logged in.

The problem is that if I click on the universal link and the user is not logged in, when he logs in, the next screen is the main screen (let's call it HomeScreen).

Let's suppose I have the next navigation structure:

```
- Auth: {
    - Login
    - Register
}

- Main: {
    - Home
    - Profile: {
        - Advanced: {
            - Settings
        }
        - Profile
    }
    - Settings
```

Imagine I have a Universal link which points to `https://example.com/profile/advanced/settings`. If I'm logged in, I navigate to the screen without any problems, if not, I get the login screen and once I log in, I stay in the Home screen.

How can I manage a redirectUrl for the login? This redirectUrl in this case would be `https://example.com/profile/advanced/settings`

Comment: good question, will look for an answer, meanwhile bookmark :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the guard inside the Settings screen

`react-navigation` does not have this functionality

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation.github.io/issues/97

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! What do you mean by adding the guard inside the settings screen?

Comment: You can create HOC https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper for the Settings screen and inside HOC write logic when you check if a user is logged and after that redirect to LogIn screen with additional params. Inside additional params, you pass what screen you need to navigate after successfully log in (settings screen for your example)

Comment: But the problem is that my `redirectUrl` is a URL, not a screen. How could I get the screen which this url stands for? I've made a working example by calling Linking.OpenUrl() but it does a small blink which is bothering me a bit.

Comment: read docs here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links/#mapping-path-to-route-names

Comment: And I prefer Firebase Dynamic Links for handling deep links https://rnfirebase.io/dynamic-links/usage With this you can avoid the automatic redirect and write custom logic to screen what you need open and coverage case with authorization